# in cakephp 3.0 i want to show all modal validation message together

Tags: validation, modal-dialog, cakephp-3.0, behavior

in cakephp 3.0 i want to show all modal validation message together above the view form. but it is showing with respective input fields. please let me know how i can re position the error message display together above in cake php 3.0.

i am successfully able to hide the error display with input fields in the form by using templates but not able to get modal error messages.

my table class is as below

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{

    $validator
        ->add('id', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->notEmpty('username','Username Must be provided')
        ->add('username', 'validFormat', [
                'rule' => ['custom' , '/^[a-z0-9]{3,}$/i'],
                'message'=>'Username must contain alphnumeric value and must be more that 3 characters']);

    $validator
        ->add('email', 'valid', ['rule' => 'email'])
        ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('email','Email Must be provided');

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('password','Password must be provided');

   $validator
        ->add('company', 'validFormat', [
                'rule' => ['custom' , '/^[a-z0-9\s,]{3,}$/i'],
                'message'=>'Company name can contain alphanumeric value only']);

    $validator
        ->add('address', 'validFormat',[
                'rule' => ['custom' , '/^[a-z0-9\s,]{3,}$/i'],
                'message'=>'Address must be alphanumeric value.'])
        ->requirePresence('address','create')
        ->notEmpty('address','Address must be provided');  

    $validator
        ->requirePresence('country_id','create')
        ->notEmpty('country_id','Country name must be provided');            

    $validator
        ->add('city', 'valid',['rule' => ['custom' , '/^[a-z0-9\s,]{3,}$/i'],'message'=>'City can containalphanumeric value only.'])
        ->requirePresence('city','create')
        ->notEmpty('city','City must be provided');  

    $validator
        ->add('phone', 'valid',['rule' => ['custom' , '/^[0-9]{10,}$/i'],'message'=>'Phone must be atleast 10 characters.'])
        ->requirePresence('phone','create')
        ->notEmpty('phone','Address must be provided');  


    return $validator;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to debug the entity? then you would notice the errors. $entity->errors();

Comment: thanks alex it works, i was doing something else. Plz refer me some tutorial site for cakephp 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to debug the entity? then you would notice the errors. $entity->errors();

try the tutorial: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html

You could have googled this yourself